# p:dataTable sorting without getters in PrimeFaces 4.0

Tags: primefaces

I have a data table that presents data but sorting does not work.

The problem is, these records don't have getFieldName getters, but getValue('FieldName'). This allows me to change the schema without recompiling.

For example, one such field is a date.

I would like some trick to make this code work, without having to create custom beans for every table, hence tightly coupled to the physical data model.

```
                    <p:column headerText="Date" sortBy="#{r.getValue('date')}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{r.getValue('date')}" />
                    </p:column>
```

Comment: I think it is better to switch to lazyLoading and just state `#{bla.date}` in the sortBy or some other fake EL that gets stripped and just returns 'date'.

Comment: For the bla.date, bla needs to implement a method getDate(), right? If so, this is what I would like to avoid. The data access layer is not aware of the field names of the tables of the application layer. So I cannot have a sortable table without creating specific beans for each database table or view.

Comment: No it does not iirc... The first part gets stripped off and in the load method in the lazyDataModel, only date is passed on. 'bla' can be anything (at least it could be).

Comment: If you could write some example code... But I will research lazy loading, thanks!

Comment: It's all in the PrimeFaces manual, showcase (remember to use the 4.0 version of both) the PrimeFaces forum and stackoverflow and the rest of the internet... If you have actual coding problems, I'm willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you want it to work is not how it is going to work in the `p:dataTable`. I'm not sure how the plain direct (non-lazy) filtering works. I've never used that and I always [implement lazy loading](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) with a lot of base classes so it is easy to implement for different entities etc and gives me full control (OptimusFaces helps here)

For LazyDataModel, the `sortBy` attribute where you need to put 'EL', is not really evaluated as EL. Not in 6.2 but iirc also not in 4.0. In fact the EL you put in there is stipped of the `#{..} and split on the dot that is expected in there. The resulting part is passed on to the load method in the filter properties.

So

```
sortBy="#{bla.myAttribute}"`
```

is passed to the load method as

```
myAttribute
```

As can be seen in LazyDataModel.java in the showcase (same is true for the filtering btw).

```
@Override
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
    List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();

    //filter
    for(Car car : datasource) {
        boolean match = true;

        if (filters != null) {
            for (Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                try {
                    String filterProperty = it.next();
                    Object filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                    String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));

                    if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue.toString())) {
                        match = true;
                }
                else {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(match) {
            data.add(car);
        }
    }

    //sort
    if(sortField != null) {
        Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
    }

    //rowCount
    int dataSize = data.size();
    this.setRowCount(dataSize);

    //paginate
    if(dataSize > pageSize) {
        try {
            return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
        }
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

(in the LazySorter, the same reflection is used on the 'Car' class as is done for the filtering: `Car.class.getField(sortField).get(...)` so that implies the whole first part in the 'EL' is stripped. And hence you can put any fake thing in front.

This makes it possible to do exactly what you want but instead of

```
sortBy="#{r.getValue('date')}"
```

just use

```
sortBy="#{myFakePrependeSomething.date}"
```

And if you want to sort on a field of an object use

```
sortBy="#{myFakePrependeSomething.item.date}"
```

and then `item.date' is passed in and you just have to do the reflection to first get the 'item' field and then the date. OptimusFaces helps with this.

Answer (score 0):

i could not bring in OptimusFaces, so i had to do it in the compare-method of the LazySorter:

to make it clear: this works out of the box with the sample compare-method provided by primefaces:

```
     <p:column headerText="Id" sortable="true" sortBy="#{obj.id}" filterable="true" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{obj.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.id}"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
```

this does not:

```
 <p:column headerText="Vorname" sortable="true" sortBy="#{obj.person.vorname}" filterable="true" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{obj.person.vorname}">
            <h:outputText value="#{obj.person.vorname }"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>
```

because the sortField which gets passed to the comparator is "obj.person.vorname" and the samplemethod only finds the fields for the parent-object like so:

```
  Field[] userFields = Obj.class.getDeclaredFields();
         for (Field field : objFields) {

             if (field.getName().equals(sortField)) {
                 field.setAccessible(true);
                 value1 = field.get(cp1);
                 value2 = field.get(cp2);
             }
         }...
```

so to get the fields of the child,

```
 if(sortField.contains("person.")){
         Field[] personFields = Personen.class.getDeclaredFields();
         String pSortField = sortField.substring(7, sortField.length());

         for(Field pField : personFields){
             if(pField.getName().equals(pSortField)){
                 pField.setAccessible(true);
                 value1 = pField.get(cp1.getPerson());
                 value2 = pField.get(cp2.getPerson());
             }
         }
     }
     else if(... do it like bevore ....
```

maybee someone could provide a more "reflective" way of doing it, the use of  "substing" here bothers me... a more generic method would be good ...

btw. it'S primefaces 8 now